# I would like to find out for which discount ids the expirationDate has changed. Here is a snapshot of the table. I will need to do a self join

Tags: sql

I would like to find out for which discount ids the expirationDate has changed. Here is a snapshot of the table. I will need to do a self join.

```
tablename  discountid  expirationdate
NEW        182150      2013-12-02 00:00:00.000
OLD        182150      2099-12-31 00:00:00.000
NEW        182151      2013-12-02 00:00:00.000
OLD        182151      2099-12-31 00:00:00.000
NEW        182152      2013-12-02 00:00:00.000
OLD        182152      2099-12-31 00:00:00.000
NEW        192608      2013-12-02 00:00:00.000
OLD        192608      2099-12-31 00:00:00.000
NEW        192609      2013-12-02 00:00:00.000
OLD        192609      2099-12-31 00:00:00.000
```

Comment: tablename discountid expirationdate
NEW 182150 2013-12-02 00:00:00.000
OLD 182150 2099-12-31 00:00:00.000
NEW 182151 2013-12-02 00:00:00.000
OLD 182151 2099-12-31 00:00:00.000
NEW 182152 2013-12-02 00:00:00.000
OLD 182152 2099-12-31 00:00:00.000
NEW 192608 2013-12-02 00:00:00.000
OLD 192608 2099-12-31 00:00:00.000
NEW 192609 2013-12-02 00:00:00.000
OLD 192609 2099-12-31 00:00:00.000

Comment: Not sure how to make the data look like a table.

Comment: What does your query look like so far?

Comment: Re: data formatting, I did it for you, but all you need to do is highlight the code or information you want formatted and click the **`{}`** icon on top of the text box.

Comment: select * from Test A, Test B
  where A.discountid = B.DiscountID and A.expirationDate!=B.expirationDate

Comment: The query above brings back the discountids which have changed but I also need to compare all the columns in the 2 rows (not showing all the columns in the data above) and find a way to to say which columns have changed. There are 2 rows per discountid.

Comment: What is that `tablename` column all about? Just based on the data in your example, it seems like it sort-of already indicates a change? Is it incorrect to query against that column instead?

Comment: It indicates a change but does not tell us which columns have changed.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

From the comments I gather that you don' only look for changes of expiration dates, but for several columns. Here is a solution:

```
select discountid
 , decode(min(a),max(a),0,1) as a_changed
 , decode(min(b),max(b),0,1) as b_changed
 , decode(min(c),max(c),0,1) as c_changed
from test
group by discountid
having 
  decode(min(a),max(a),1,0) = 0 or
  decode(min(b),max(b),1,0) = 0 or
  decode(min(c),max(c),1,0) = 0;
```

EDIT: For non-Oracle dbms:

```
select discountid
 , case when (min(a) = max(a) then 0 else 1 end as a_changed
 , case when (min(b) = max(b) then 0 else 1 end as b_changed
 , case when (min(c) = max(c) then 0 else 1 end as c_changed
from test
group by discountid
having 
  min(a) <> max(a) or
  min(b) <> max(b) or
  min(c) <> max(c);
```

Comment: Sorry, this did not work for me. I get this error. 'decode' is not a recognized built-in function name.

Comment: Done. However, the non-Oracle query doesn't regard changes from or to NULL. You will have to change the comparisions accordingly, if you want to detect those, too.

Comment: Thank you so much. I was able to figure out how to do the select part in sql server but not the conditions after 'having'. I believe this is the solution I was looking for. Thanks again.

Comment: @Ann Don't forget to "accept" Thorsten's answer if it did indeed help you (or whichever one helped you most).

Answer (score 1):

Here is one way to find the ids having two different expiration dates in the table:

```
select discountid
from mytable
group by discountid
having count(distinct expirationdate) > 1;
```

Comment: Thanks, your query is better than the one I have but please see what I really need.

Answer (score 1):

You may try one of the following two:

```
SELECT NEW.discountid, OLD.expirationdate, NEW.expirationdate 
FROM NEW JOIN OLD ON(NEW.discountid=OLD.discountid) 
WHERE OLD.expirationdate != NEW.expirationdate
```

(if NEW and OLD are your two tables)

or

```
SELECT NEW.discountid, OLD.expirationdate,NEW.expirationdate 
FROM SINGTAB NEW JOIN SINGTAB OLD ON(NEW.discountid=OLD.discountid) 
WHERE NEW.tablename='NEW' AND OLD.tablename='OLD' AND OLD.expirationdate != NEW.expirationdate
```

(if the data is in a table named SINGTAB, and tablename is a column in SINGTAB)

Comment: The query above brings back the discountids which have changed but I also need to compare all the columns in the 2 rows (not showing all the columns in the data above) and find a way to to say which columns have changed. There are 2 rows per discountid.

Comment: Sorry, my crystal ball currently is at the repair shop.